# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') - what do I oversee?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const {groups} = require('../../groups.json')

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('groupcreate')
        .setDescription('Creates a Role Group')
        .addStringOption(option =>`your text`
            option.setName('name')
                .setDescription('Name for the group')
                .setRequired(true)),`your text`

    async execute(interaction) {
        let group = {
            name: interaction.options.getString('name'),
            data: []
        }

        var file = fs.readFileSync('groups.json');
        if (file.length == 0) {
            fs.writeFileSync('groups.json', JSON.stringify([group]))
        } else {
            groups.push(group);
            fs.writeFileSync('groups.json', JSON.stringify(groups, null, 2))
        }

        await interaction.reply({content: `Creating Group: ${interaction.options.getString('name')}`});
    },
};
```

Error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
> at Object.execute (C:\Users\User\Desktop\TestBot\Commands\RolesTest\groupcreate.js:22:20)

Comment: What's the content of the `groups.json` file? Are you sure you want to destructure that? Shouldn't it be `const groups = require('../../groups.json')`?

Comment: The groups.json just contains
 [
    
]

as I usually intend to write the name of the group I want to create into that file using the Slashcommand

Comment: what is the value of `groups` inside the json file? Please be noted that `push` is a method of dealing with array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `groups` here.

> ```
> const {groups} = require('../../groups.json')
> ```

You are trying to [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) an object and assign the value of its `groups` property to the `groups` const.

Later you try to treat `groups` as if it was an array.

This means you expect the format of *groups.json* to be:

```json
{
    "groups": []
}
```

---

Later you try to write to *groups.json* with:

> ```
> fs.writeFileSync('groups.json', JSON.stringify([group]))
> ```

This means you expect the format of *groups.json* to be:

```json
[]
```

---

These don't match!

`groups` will be `undefined` if the file contains an array instead of an object with a groups property.

You need to pick one of the two formats and be consistent with how you use it.

i.e. change your read operation to:

```
const groups = require('../../groups.json');
```

or change your write operations to:

```
 fs.writeFileSync('groups.json', JSON.stringify({ groups: [group]}))
```

and

```
 fs.writeFileSync('groups.json', JSON.stringify({groups}, null, 2))
```